# Simple convert Hex parts into Number C#

Tags: c#, hex

How can I convert a Hex String into numbers and calc the sum in an simple way.

I want cut the string every second char --> BB6050C9 ---> BB|60|50|C9

```
String shex = "BB6050C9";
int sum;
```

with shex.Substring(....) i can cut the string but how can I convert the String into a number and sum it in an simple way ?

> 0xBB=187, 0x60=97, 0x50=80, 0xC9=201,

```
sum=187+97+80+201;
```

Comment: It sounds like you *really* want to parse the hex string into a byte array. After that, the rest is easy. There are lots of SO questions about parsing hex in C#.

Comment: ah okk, I'm just an beginner with c# :) I was looking for the right word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SoapHexBinary.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then sum the bytes returned by `Value` property.

```
var shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse("BB6050C9");
var sum = shb.Value.Sum(x => x);//returns 564
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code :-

```
var output = 0;
            string input = "BB6050C9";
            char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char letter in values)
            {
                // Get the integral value of the character. 
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
                // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form. 
                string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
                Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1}", letter, hexOutput);
                output += Convert.ToInt32(hexOutput);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "BB6050C9";
const int chunkSize = 2;
var sum = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(x => str.Substring(x * chunkSize, chunkSize))
        .Sum(x => int.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a hex-byte string (ie 2 chars) then the value is:

```
16 * "0123456789abcdef".IndexOf(hex.ToLower()[0]) + "0123456789abcdef".IndexOf(hex.ToLower()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the string using a regular expression, parse the number using `Convert.ToInt32` and sum up the values like this:

```
int sum = Regex.Matches(shex, "..").Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Value, 16))
  .Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String hex = "BB6050C9";  

    int i = 0;
    long sum = 0;

    while (i + 2 <= hex.Length)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt64(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        i += 2;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
```